# How to remove shadow from dialog? android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am using AppCompatDialog to build dialog interface.

My goal is remove shadow around dialog view when it shows?

here is example of code:

```
private void showWrongLoginPassDialog(String message){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.ad_login_error_title));
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ad_login_error_positive),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        builder.show();
    }
```

Comment: `AlertDialog dialog = builder.create(); dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)); dialog.show();`

Comment: you were close )
dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND‌​);
dialog.show();

this was helpful )

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this, it works for me

```
dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

For you:     `builder.show().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND‌​);`

Comment: AlertDialog dialog = builder.create(); dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND‌​);
dialog.show();

this one is right

Answer (score 1):

The right answer for this question is

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

For me works like a charm. Hope it helps someone

Comment: On API 22, phone generated some dark gray top padding, your answer removed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use a custom theme for your dialog. This custom theme worked for me.

```
 <style name="MenuDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <!--This attribute removes the shadow-->
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <!--This attribute updates the background color of the window-->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <!--Optional: This attribute makes the dialog window non-floating-->
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>
```

Now, use the theme in following way

```
 AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MenuDialog);
```